# neo4j cypher query to get the first post of each user

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to get the first post of each user, from a group of users.

(Imagining that nodes 1, 2, 3 4 are user nodes)

This query returns the single earliest post between all users:

```
START user=node(1, 2, 3, 4)
MATCH user <-[:creator]- post
WITH user, min(post.createdAt) as earliest
MATCH user <-[:creator]- post
WHERE post.createdAt = earliest
RETURN post
```

What query would return the earliest/first post of each user?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should give you what you want (the earliest post for *each* user):

```
START user=node(1, 2, 3, 4)
MATCH user <-[:creator]- post
WITH user, min(post.createdAt) as earliest

MATCH (user2) <-[:creator]- (post2 {createdAt : earliest})
WHERE ID(user2) = ID(user)

RETURN user2,post
```

The first part of your query appears correct, but in your second MATCH statement you were looking for any (user)<-[:creator]-(post) where the post has the earliest createdAt time.  As you point out this will only return a single (probably) entry.

In order to get the earliest post per user, your second MATCH needs to somehow specify each user explicitly.  My example uses a **WHERE ID(user2) = ID(user)** but there is at least one other way which may be preferable.  If you have a unique property for users, then you could specify the property value just like **(post2 {createdAt:earliest})** in my example.  For example you could do something like **(user2 {username:user.username})**.  Note in all of my examples that you should also use another variable name in the second MATCH statement to disambiguate the query if nothing else (I'm not clear whether it would work with the same variable name, but it's definitely more confusing if they're the same).

Also, I'm assuming you're shorthanding the query, and you're probably using labels, so the query would look something like this:

```
 START user=node(1, 2, 3, 4)
 MATCH (user:USER) <-[:creator]- (post:POST)
 WITH user, min(post.createdAt) as earliest

 MATCH (user2:USER) <-[:creator]- (post2:POST {createdAt : earliest})
 WHERE ID(user2) = ID(user)

 RETURN user2,post
```

I hope that's clear, feel free to clarify if it's not.